# jquery multidatepicker min date disturbs datepickers UI

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

**Concept :** I am creating a calendar of one year.
say **01-01-2017 to 31-12-2017**.
 **Issue :**  when i set **min date to 08-06-2017** then datepicker goes rearranged and it becomes a **datepicker of 01-06-2017 to 31-05-2018**
what i need is it should start from `1 jan 2017` and ends with `31 dec 2017`

js code :

```
$('#generate_sampling .full-year').multiDatesPicker({
    addDates: dates,
    numberOfMonths: (samplingStatus=="EDIT" ? [3,4] : [6,4]),
    minDate : startDate,
    maxDate : endDate,
    defaultDate :  '01/30/'+(year == '' ? '2017' : year),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i managed to stop rearrangement of dates. i added some conditions under **beforeShowDay** and commented my min and max date parameters

```
$('#generate_sampling .full-year').multiDatesPicker({
        addDates: dates, // array of dates
        numberOfMonths:  [3,4] ,
        /*minDate : startDate,
        maxDate : endDate,*/
        defaultDate :  '01/30/'+(year == '' ? '2017' : year),

        beforeShowDay: function(dateStamp) {
            var className="";
            if(dateStamp < new Date(startDate) || dateStamp > new Date(endDate)){
                className =" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "
            }
            var title = "Disabled";
            return [true, className ,title]; // title will be displayed as tooltip
        }
});
```

In case **beforeShowDay** is not working please check your  multidatepickers core js file. this below line must be commented . uncomment it. it will work.

```
this.multiDatesPicker.originalBeforeShowDay = options.beforeShowDay;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$('.full-year').multiDatesPicker('destroy');
```

Destroy the Datepicker before you set `minDate`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xov4xn2q/)

Comment: thanks for replying but its not working, even demo is not related to my question. just change first line of src with datepicker("17-3-1","17-12-31"); datepicker will starts from march.. which i dont want.. i want that datepicker to start always with january.

Comment: Just to ask,is there any event called to set 'minDate' after initialization of datepicker?in your question its mentioned when u set 'minDate' datepicker gets rearranged.